# Python: Create ndarray from a custom file format fast

Tags: python, parsing, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a file format that looks like this

```
0.1
0.02 0.03 0.04
0.05 0.06 0.07
0.08 0.09 0.10
0.2
0.11 0.12 0.13
0.14 0.15 0.16
0.17 0.18 0.19
0.3 ... ...
```

I want to parse this file to an array for that looks like this -

```
0.02 0.11 ...
0.03 0.12 ...
0.04 0.13 ...
0.05 0.14 ...
0.06 0.15 ...
0.07 0.16 ...
...
```

Here I have determined that genfromtxt, loadtxt would not work because of the intermediate lines with a single column. I do not know there could be more blocks of data and I do not know how many till the end of file. I am manually entering individual entries into an array right now. Is there a faster way to do this? I am looking to parse large files and many of them.

Comment: So the blocks are always 3x3?

Comment: No the blocks are not always 3x3 but they are of the known size so your solution works! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the whole file content at once, `split` the string at spaces and line breaks and `join` the pieces in the required order: every tenth element in one line, then a new line and so on:

```
import re

with open("data.txt") as f:
    content = re.split(' |\n', f.read())
    print "\n".join([" ".join(content[i::10]) for i in range(1, 10)])
```

Content of file `data.txt`:

```
0.1
0.02 0.03 0.04
0.05 0.06 0.07
0.08 0.09 0.10
0.2
0.11 0.12 0.13
0.14 0.15 0.16
0.17 0.18 0.19
0.3
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Output:

```
0.02 0.11 1
0.03 0.12 2
0.04 0.13 3
0.05 0.14 4
0.06 0.15 5
0.07 0.16 6
0.08 0.17 7
0.09 0.18 8
0.10 0.19 9
```

Answer (score 0):

You could read the file a line at a time then split by space then iterate over that and split by the period character. Then format the integer part and fractional portion like so.

```
"{0:d}.{0:>2d}".format(characteristic, mantissa)
```